# Is it possible to locally validate, accept, and store certain media types with an HTML/JS form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

This is a bit of a strange question - I'm designing an ad production specification sheet and template for a client's clients. I have good basic knowledge of HTML/CSS, and could probably cobble together a rudimentary JS plugin if need be. This client requested that I use PowerPoint for this template, but I'd much rather attempt to do this with an HTML form. TL;DR - here's my question:

Would it be possible to provide a zipped folder containing a localized "site" that allows his clients to drop their media and text into an HTML form?

I know this isn't optimal, but I lack server-side experience and he probably won't be willing to pay someone to do back-end work (that is, I doubt we could add this form to his website). I suppose I'd need to write a plugin to process the input, place it into a specified folder, and then display a screenshot of the media and text integrated into the UI that it will eventually be displayed in.

Comment: I still not understood your question completely. You you want check something in the client maybe you can try something like [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FFileReader)

Comment: I was trying to say that I'd like to build a UI with HTML and CSS, and just deliver that along with an integrated JS plugin to each client from whom we need media. It should function like an upload form on a website, except that the "site" will reside in a folder that I send to the client. The only function that the site will serve is provision of a GUI, checks of a few basic properties of the "uploaded" media files and text (file type, image resolution, etc.), ensuring that the types and properties fall within specified ranges for each field, and storing each file in an appropriate location.

Comment: Basically you want create a new site by just upload in js? It wont work because it will be accessible just by you. Even if you save in localStorage or something like this it's a very limited approach.